# How to search datetime value in JSONB using ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, jsonb, ransack

This is a sample code that searches key value inside jsonb_column for `name`

```
ransacker :name do |parent|    
  Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->>', parent.table[:jsonb_column_here], 
  Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('name'))
end
```

**BEFORE** we're not using JSONB column and this works for searching using datetime values.

```
 Ransack.configure do |config|
  config.add_predicate 'between_begin_and_end',
                       arel_predicate: 'between_begin_and_end',
                       formatter: proc { |v| v.to_date },
                       validator: proc { |v| v.present? },
                       type: :string
end

module Arel
  module Predications
    def between_begin_and_end date
      gteq(date.to_date.beginning_of_day).and(lt(date.end_of_day))
    end
  end
end


**Example data:**

jsonb_column {
  "data_created_at"=>2020-03-23 05:10:46 UTC,
  ....
  ....
}
```

**HOW** to incorporate my previous method now with JSONB column.

Comment: JSON does not even have a date or time type. What is it that you are actually storing? A epoc integer? An ISO8601 timestamp? I would just go back to NOT using a column JSON and actually having typed data and sanity if possible.

Comment: Hi @max, added sample saved data